# Check the convergence of the series $\sum (-1)^{n} n(1- \cos (a/n))$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Check the convergence of the series $\sum (-1)^{n} n(1- \cos (a/n))$

$S = \sum (-1)^{n} n( \sin ^{2} ( a/2n))$
$S = \sum (-1)^{n}( \sin^{2} (a/2n)/(1/n))$

Then I don't know how to proceed. 
I am not able to find any suitable test for this series.

Any hint$?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n(1-\cos \frac an) \approx \frac {a^2}{2n}$

You can use a limit comparison test between these two sequences to show that the series is not absolutely convergent.

To show it is conditionally convergent use the alternating series test.

i) Show that the series is alternating

ii) $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} c_n = 0$

iii) $\forall n>N, |c_{n+1}| < |c_n|$